# Syslog-NG filtering with tags - RHEL 7.x

Tags: linux, configuration, syslog-ng

In the below list of syslog messages:

```
# tail -9 /var/log/messages 
Oct  9 14:15:39 machine1 puppet-agent[14371]: Finished catalog run in 6.68 seconds
Oct  9 14:45:31 machine1 puppet-agent[12234]: The package type's allow_virtual parameter will be changing its default value from false to true in a future release. If you do not want to allow virtual packages, please explicitly set allow_virtual to false.
Oct  9 14:45:31 machine1 puppet-agent[100174]:   (at /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type.rb:816:in `set_default')
Oct  9 14:45:32 machine1 auditd[1084]: Audit daemon rotating log files
Oct  9 14:45:37 machine1 puppet-agent[100174]: Finished catalog run in 5.71 seconds
Oct  9 15:15:30 machine1 puppet-agent[102964]: The package type's allow_virtual parameter will be changing its default value from false to true in a future release. If you do not want to allow virtual packages, please explicitly set allow_virtual to false.
Oct  9 15:15:30 machine1 puppet-agent[102964]:   (at /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type.rb:816:in `set_default')
Oct  9 15:15:37 machine1 puppet-agent[102964]: Finished catalog run in 6.31 seconds
Oct  9 15:21:17 machine1 su: (to root) user1 on pts/0
```

---

sample tags are `puppet-agent[14371]`, `auditd[1084]` & `su` etc...

To filter syslog messages based on tags **without** process id, we use `program` filter, as shown below:

```
filter tag_based{ program(puppet_agent); };
```

But, every tag **may or may not be** appended with processid, as per above messages.

---

How to filter tags appended with/without process id?

Comment: The $MSGHDR macro contains the programname and the PID  in PROGRAM[PID]: format. The $PID macro contains only the PID.

Comment: @RobertFekete  So... Does `filter tag_based{ program(puppet_agent); };` work fine?

Comment: Yes, it should IMHO.